# How to retrieve data from database when want to retrieve data dynamically

Tags: mysql, node.js

How can I retrieve data from database(MySQL) dynamically in NodeJS when having more than one events in the database table. In the below code, I am getting data in text variable...have checked it via console but want it to get retrieved from SQL query ....so what is the correct way to get the data dynamically via query

```
console.log("enter to db-----------------",text)
connection.query("SELECT Description FROM tegbot_v4_xlsx WHERE Name=text",  async function (error, rows, fields) 
{                              
    if (!!error) 
    {
        console.log(`Error in the query`)
    }
    else 
    {
        console.log(`Successful query\n`);
        console.log('hello---------', rows[0].Description)
        await dc.context.sendActivity(rows.Description)
    }
})
```

Comment: What is the exact issue you are facing while trying the above code ?

Comment: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'Description' of undefined....